# JCenter и Maven

Tags: maven, android-gradle

Я раньше думала, что JCenter и Maven - это разные хранилища библиотек. Вот и подтверждение этой мысли из [статьи на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/266801/):

> jCenter считается крупнейшим хранилищем Java библиотек, но в то же
>   время многие разработчики предпочитают Maven Central. Не стоит
>   забывать, что jCenter и Maven Central являются физически разными
>   серверами, и наличие библиотеки в одном не гарантирует её наличие в
>   другом.

Но сегодня в книге (в главе с описанием файла build.gradle в Android Studio) я наткнулась на следующие строки :

> Here, jcenter() is a built-in method that sets up the repository
>   information for Maven Central, a popular location for obtaining open
>   source dependencies.

Получается, из последней фразы вытекает, что jCenter и Maven Central - это одно и то же? Или я неправильно что-то понимаю, или в книге допущена ошибка, опечатка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven Central - это Maven репозиторий, расположенный по адресу  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
jCenter - это Maven репозиторий, расположенный по адресу https://jcenter.bintray.com/

Да, это физически 2 разных сервиса.

По поводу фразы из книги:
В [документации](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#jcenter()) Gradle четко сказано:

> The URL used to access this repository is "https://jcenter.bintray.com/". The behavior of this repository is otherwise the same as those added by maven(org.gradle.api.Action).

Так же в Gradle есть:

- `mavenCentral()` для указания Maven Central
- `mavenLocal()` для
  указания локального Maven репозитория
- `google()` для указания
  https://maven.google.com (добавлено с версии 4.0)

Comment: Так в книге ошибка, или же всё правильно?)

Comment: @Ksenia в книге ошибка. верный вариант процитирован из документации :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! :)